# Power series solution for a DE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Could someone help me solve the following DE problem using power series?

(x+2)y' +2y = 0, y(1/2)= 1/5

I tried substituting with:

$y(x) =\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = a_0 + \sum_{1}^{\infty} a_nx^n $

$y'(x) = a_1 + \sum_{1}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1} x^n$

our eq,

$=>  (x+2)( a_1 + \sum_{1}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1} x^n) + 2(a_0 + \sum_{1}^{\infty} a_nx^n ) = 0 $

Let $m = n+1 $ we get,

$ a_1(x+2) + x\sum_{1}^{\infty}ma_{m} x^n + 2\sum_{1}^{\infty}ma_{m} x^n+ 2a_0 + 2\sum_{1}^{\infty} a_nx^n = 0 $

=>

(1) : $ a_1(x+2) + 2a_0 = 0$

(2) : $ \sum_{1}^{\infty} ma_mx^{x+1} + 2\sum_{1}^{\infty} ma_mx^n + \sum_{1}^{\infty} a_nx^n = 0$

I don't know how to continue from here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is expansion around zero or 1/2 ?

Comment: I think it's around 1/2, this is the only info I've got

Comment: Thank you so so much! I've learned a lot from your detailed explanation!